# While loop or On Time function when running script with a set time interval

Tags: excel, vba

I am have an Excel sheet that pushes in values every second. I would like to capture that and log it on a separate sheet every 5 seconds.

I am currently torn between using a `Do While` loop and the `OnTime` method. I was wondering what will be the pros and cons with using either methods. Or if there is a better way of periodically executing scripts, I am all ears as well.

Do While method:

```
Sub mainSub()
    'On/Off
    Do While Sheets("Main").Range("B3") = 1
        'script to transfer prices
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Loop
End Sub
```

On Time method:

```
Sub mainSub()
    'On/Off
    If Sheets("Main").Range("B3") = 1 Then
        Call capturePriceSub
    End If
End Sub

Sub capturePriceSub()
    'script to transfer prices
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), mainSub

End Sub
```

Comment: Never do `Do While`. Always use `Application.OnTime`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate further on why this is the case? Both methods seems to have the same end results.

Comment: The first one ties up processing - the second does not.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Correct.